# pycharm - how do i find replace a word in my entire project?

Tags: pycharm

As the question asks, how do i run a find/replace in pycharm for a word over the entire project?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`Edit` | `Find` | [Replace in Path](http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/webhelp/finding-and-replacing-text-in-project.html).

Shortcut: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>

Comment: Alternative: right click on project name (in project explorer) >> `Find in Path...`

Answer (score 5):

For those here coming from Google and that only want to **find** something in the entire project:
`CTRL+H`

For a replace, there is no keyboard shortcut.

Comment: That seems to just bring up the Hierarchy Class MainWindow in my case

Comment: I was probably set up with default or Eclipse keyboard shortcuts in PyCharm at the time of posting this. What is your shortcut, and with which settings do you have?

Answer (score 2):

## [Quick Answer]

- Find and Replace in the project ==> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>
- Find and Replace in a local file ==> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>

---

[**NOTE**]:

Sometimes, it has adjusted to <kbd>H</kbd> instead of <kbd>R</kbd>